# Calling Drupal Form from non-Drupal 3rd Party Website

Tags: forms

I have an existing non-Drupal 3rd party site and I am trying to submit a form request to a site written in Drupal. For some reason, the request does not process. I'm not familiar with Drupal and would appreciate any help that can be offered.

An expected response would be:

> "No match found for AMA 123456 and last name smith. Please verify."

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :-)! We love to help. Please don't include links to your site that have no value as soon as your issue got fixed. We provide canonical answers to reproducible problems that hopefully help future readers as well. So please update your question and provide enough information to let us understand your problem without a link to your site. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

you'll probably need to post some sort of code to help us understand whats going on.

- What version of Drupal are you on?
- What HTTP status code is coming back from Drupal?
- if its a status 200, Are there any errors, messages etc being returned?

but at a high level, Drupal protects against CSRF and the 3rd party site submitting a form on the Drupal site would run afoul of this protection.

potential solutions:

- You can disable the CSRF (not recommended).
- you can embed the form as an iframe
- you can create a REST resource and use that to submit the submission from the 3rd party (bypass the form)

read more https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/security/writing-secure-code/create-forms-in-a-safe-way-to-avoid-cross-site-request-forgeries

Comment: Thanks Francis. I'm not familiar with Drupal and wasn't aware of the CSRF protection. That would explain why I couldn't simply post a URL from my site and get a response. I'll reach out to the site owner about enabling a REST alternative.